# Building wxWidgets with WXUNIV=1 fails

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to compile wxWidgets with the "WXUNIV=1" and it doesn't seem to work on any 3.X.X version. The first version that worked was 2.9.5. Sadly this version is too old to replace the version that I'm using currently (3.1.1).

The steps I'm using to compile are based on https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/plat_msw_install.html.

1. CD to "wxWidgets-3.1.5\build\msw" with the VS command line and run "`nmake /f makefile.vc BUILD=release SHARED=1 TARGET_CPU=X86 WXUNIV=1`".

This will give the following error:

> D:\wxWidgets-3.1.5\include\wx/msw/chkconf.h(34): fatal error C1189:
> #error: "wxUSE_WINRT must be defined."
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.EXE"'
> : return code '0x2'
> Stop.

2. Trying to undef `wxABORT_ON_CONFIG_ERROR` (I know it's not recommended, but it was worth a try) will cause linking errors.

Any idea what might be causing this?

EDIT: I've tried to #define:

```
wxUSE_WINRT

wxUSE_TASKBARBUTTON

wxUSE_DBGHELP
```

a.k.a the defines which were causing errors. This is the same as undef-ing `wxABORT_ON_CONFIG_ERROR`. I get the following linking errors:

```
    coredll_graphcmn.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class wxGraphicsRenderer * __cdecl wxGraphicsRenderer::GetDefaultRenderer(void)" (?GetDefaultRenderer@wxGraphicsRenderer@@SAPAV1@XZ)
    coredll_statbmpg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class wxGraphicsRenderer * __cdecl wxGraphicsRenderer::GetDefaultRenderer(void)" (?GetDefaultRenderer@wxGraphicsRenderer@@SAPAV1@XZ)
    coredll_richtooltipg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class wxGraphicsRenderer * __cdecl wxGraphicsRenderer::GetDefaultRenderer(void)" (?GetDefaultRenderer@wxGraphicsRenderer@@SAPAV1@XZ)
    coredll_dcgraph.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct HDC__ * __thiscall wxGCDC::AcquireHDC(void)" (?AcquireHDC@wxGCDC@@UAEPAUHDC__@@XZ)
    coredll_dcgraph.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall wxGCDC::ReleaseHDC(struct HDC__ *)" (?ReleaseHDC@wxGCDC@@UAEXPAUHDC__@@@Z)
    ..\..\lib\vc_dll\wxmswuniv315u_core_vc_custom.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
```

Comment: what is the reason you want a universal build on Windows? And did you try to follow suggestion - define `wxUSE_WINRT`?

Comment: I'm trying to support dark mode for a Windows application and the common wxWidgets build didn't seem to offer options for some controls. From what I've seen, the universal build allows way more flexibility.

Comment: @Igor I've tried defining the stuff that was reported as undefined. This causes the same linking errors. I've added an EDIT in the original post.

Comment: I understand. The problem is that witrh the 3.x version Universal port on Windows is not built. And therefore not tested. And so every single problem you will find - you will be on your own. There was a recent discussion in the ML about `dark mode` - did you see it? If not - I suggest to find that thread in the ML archive.

Comment: there is a lot of work done to support dark mode on Windows for the latest release of wxWidgets. Try it out with the native MSW port. If you find something that doesn't work - please don't hesitate to report it to github.com/wxwidgets/issues. As of now it looks like one of the top priorities for core wx-devs,

Answer (score 0):

wxUniv port is not ready for production use, except in very limited circumstances, so if you're going to use it, especially with something other than X11 backend, you need to be prepared to work on it yourself and, in particular, fix bugs in it.

This one should be quite simple to fix, it's just a missing `#if` (WinRT and debughlp can be used even with wxUniv, i.e. they depend on platform and not the UI port used, while task bar button should be disabled in wxUniv as it's not implemented there), but it's just the beginning as you'll surely run into more problems later. If you're motivated to work on them, please do, by all means, but I just wanted to warn you that you shouldn't expect this port to be of the same quality as the 3 main ones (MSW/GTK/Mac) or even wxQt.